# Context.getString causing "no such static field"

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a string from my strings.xml file inside an event handler, although I'm getting "No such static field".

Here is my code:

```
mSearchEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            Context context = view.getContext();

            if (hasFocus && mSearchEditText.getText().toString().trim() == context.getString(R.string.searchbar_address_label)) {
                mSearchEditText.setText("");
            }
            else if (!hasFocus && mSearchEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                mSearchEditText.setText(context.getString(R.string.searchbar_address_label));
            }
        }
    });
```

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks

UPDATE: This code was intended to show a hint inside the EditText. The R.string seems to be unavailable inside listener's functions. So, consider my question as "Is there a native way to show hints inside EditText instead of writing my own code?"

Comment: I think the error is not in the getString method, because if I inspect the value of R.string.search_address_label the error also happens.

Comment: are you trying the text to be removed as user enters the edittext?

Comment: That was my intention with this code. I didn't know edittext has a hint property and it Works this way.

Comment: you can modify your question for helping someone else.

Comment: I didn't remove the previous contents of the question so the other answers don't lose the meaning.

Comment: if you got the point then upvote my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `context.getResources().getString(R.string.searchbar_address_label);`

for setting hint use `android:hint="your_text"` 
in xml layout. or same can be done programmatically using edittext.sethint("text");

Comment: The error comes at runtime. It seems that I don't have access to R.string at event handlers, because outside the setOnFocusChangeListener it works.

Comment: i think you are trying to set the hint for edittext,am i right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't know it works this way. :)
Thank you.

Comment: try using the context of your activity not the view.

Answer (score 1):

In this situations, rebuilding project and uninstalling the app from device might help. 
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have identical ids among all project XML what is forbidden.

It can also be that you reference to an XML with identical filename and there is no such id.